# ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts Module not found : error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'

Tags: .net, node.js, angular

I am using .Net core 2.0.3 with 3rd party package. I am getting the below error while using 'dotnet publish' command.

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.8.50001 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

WebApplication6 -> D:\incident\WebApp_95367a2a\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\WebApplication6.dll
  npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
  npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 116 packages in 17.679s
  Hash: 8dde8c59d57adf41d181f75d6401e1c57572e1e2
  Version: webpack 2.5.1
  Child
      Hash: 8dde8c59d57adf41d181
      Time: 50549ms
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
      89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
      4dc129540072fa1a1317a8dbeee744f7.svg   146 kB          [emitted]
      c848e0404000287e4fd9d523dd8345e3.svg   264 kB          [emitted]  [big]
                                 vendor.js   194 kB       0  [emitted]         vendor
                                vendor.css  2.69 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
  Child
      Hash: f75d6401e1c57572e1e2
      Time: 50650ms
                                     Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
      89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   109 kB          [emitted]
      4dc129540072fa1a1317a8dbeee744f7.svg   146 kB          [emitted]
      c848e0404000287e4fd9d523dd8345e3.svg   264 kB          [emitted]  [big]
                                 vendor.js  5.62 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  vendor
  Hash: 4adcf6db79fc4d90effdc8259013a005d149ec9e
  Version: webpack 2.5.1
  Child
      Hash: 4adcf6db79fc4d90effd
      Time: 19523ms
               Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
      main-client.js  268 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-client

```
  ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

Module not found : error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\incident\WebApp_95367a2a\ClientApp' [D:\incident\WebApp_95367a2a\WebApplication6.csproj]
       @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts 5:0-95
  Child
      Hash: c8259013a005d149ec9e
      Time: 19525ms
               Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
      main-server.js  1.81 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main-server

```
  ERROR in ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts
```

Module not found : error : Can't resolve './../$$_gendir/ClientApp/app/app.server.module.ngfactory' in 'D:\incident\WebApp_95367a2a\ClientApp' [D:\incident\WebApp_95367a2a\WebApplication6.csproj]
       @ ./ClientApp/boot.server.ts 8:0-94
D:\incident\WebApp_95367a2a\WebApplication6.csproj(41,5): error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and I rename files like this *boot.browse.ts* and *boot.serve.ts* and  run *dotnet restore  src/yourprojectname.sin* . if you do this and i think it will get another error like webpack issues (your project using webpack) .It will be easy

Comment: Viraj, How is this a solution to Subha's problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Open your file boot.server.ts
On line where zone is defined (probably line 22) change it to

```
    const zone: NgZone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);
```

It was submitted as a bug for JavaScriptServices.

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1282